# Spivak, Ch. 26, Prob 3(b): $z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_0$ (real coeff.) can be written as product of linear $z+a$ and quadratic $z^2+az+b$ factors.

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers, solution-verification

The following problem is from Chapter 26, "Complex Functions" from Spivak's *Calculus*

> 3. (a) Prove that if $a_0,...,a_{n-1}$ are any complex numbers, then there are complex numbers $z_1,...,z_n$ (not necessarily distinct)
>    such that
>
> $$z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_0=\prod_{i=1}^n(z-z_i)$$
>
> (b) Prove that if $a_0,...,a_{n-1}$ are real, then
> $z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_0$ can be written as a product of linear
> factors $z+a$ and quadratic factors $z^2+az+b$ all of whose
> coefficients are real. (Use Problem 25-7).

**My question is about item (b).** My proof is at the end, but before I show a proof of part (a) and the results proved in the cited Problem 25-7.

**Here is a proof of (a) by induction.**

> For $n=1$ our complex polynomial is simply $z+a_0$ which we can write
> as $z-z_0$ where $z_0=-a_0$.
>
> Now as our inductive hypothesis assume that
> $z^{n-1}+b_{n-2}z^{n-2}+...+b_0=\prod_{i=2}^n (z-z_i)$ for
> $b_0,b_1,...,b_{n-2}$ any complex numbers.
>
> Consider $z^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+a_{n-2}x^{n-2}+...+a_0=0\tag{1}$
>
> The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra implies that (1) has a complex root
> $z_1$.
>
> Therefore, we can write (1) as
> $$(z-z_1)(z^{n-1}+b_{n-2}z^{n-2}+...+b_0)=(z-z_1)\prod_{i=2}^n
> > (z-z_i)=\prod_{i=1}^n (z-z_i)$$
>
> By induction we have our desired result.

**Let me recall what was proved in the cited Problem 25-7.**

> 25-7 (a) If $a_0,...,a_{n-1}$ are real numbers, $a$ and $b$ are real
> numbers, and $a+bi$ satisfies $$z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_0=0\tag{2}$$
> then $a-bi$ satisfies (2) as well.

That is, complex roots occur in conjugate pairs.

> 25-7 (b) $z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_0$ is divisible by
> $z^2-2az+(a^2+b^2)$

Since $a+bi$ and $a-bi$ are roots, then so is the product $$(z-(a+bi))\cdot (z-(a-bi))=z^2-2az+(a^2+b^2)$$

**So, now to item (b) proper.**

The result from part (a) applies if $a_0,...,a_{n-1}$ are real numbers (since they are also complex). Ie, there are complex $z_1,...,z_n$ (not necessarily distinct) such that

$$z^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_0=\prod_{i=1}^n(z-z_i)\tag{3}$$

Now, if a $z_i$ is non-real, then by 25-7(a) $\overline{z_i}$ is also one of the roots and the product $(z-z_i)\cdot (z-\overline{z_i})$ is a quadratic with real coefficients. If $z_i$ is a real root, then we have a linear factor $(z-z_i)$.

Thus, the right-hand side of (3) is a product of linear factors and quadratic factors with real coefficients.

Is this proof of (b) correct?

Comment: If you can use the fundamental theorem of algebra anyway , wouldn't it be much easier to use that complex roots occur in conjugate pairs if the coefficients are real ? For each such pair, we get a quadratic factor with real coefficients which can easily be shown.

Comment: @Peter - that is *exactly* what evianpring uses in the proof. The write-up is wordy and a bit wonky, but this is par for the course for this level. Evianpring, the only real relevant issue I see is a disconnect in indexing between your inductive hypothesis and conclusion in (a). Of course the two indexings are equivalent, but the point of the inductive step is to show from the hypothesis for $n$ that the hypothesis for $n+1$ is also true. Thus the very odd change of indexing just adds a pointless complication to your reader. That is poor practice.